# JHipster - entity generation - dynamic filtering for the entities

Tags: jhipster

I have created a new jhipster project v4.13.3.

When creating a entity e.g.:

```
jhipster entity Employee
```

And selecting ***Dynamic filtering for the entities with JPA Static metamodel***

An **EmployeeQueryService** class is subsequently created.

When looking in this class at the createSpecfication method, there are entries like this:

```
(buildStringSpecification(criteria.getFirstName(), Employee_.firstName));
```

**Employee_** as far as I can tell is not defined anywhere and Intellij reports "*cannot resolve symbol*".

Running `mvn`, no errors are reported and the app runs fine.

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [documented](http://www.jhipster.tech/entities-filtering/), JPA static metamodel is generated by an annotation processor at build time. Maven knows about it, your IDE doesn't.

Comment: Oh I see, Thanks Gaël